# Using XDocument to figure out if an element exists with a specific attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to use LINQ and XDocument to remove an entry from an XML document based on specific criteria like so:

```
xml.Descendants("Photos").Where(e => e.Attribute("File").Value.Equals(ID)).Remove();
```

However, in the cases where there are no entries found, it throws a *NullReferenceException* error. I've tried to get a count of all elements that match but unfortunately I get the same error:

```
public void Delete(string ID)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    var count = xml.Descendants("Photos").Where(e => e.Attribute("File").Value.Equals(ID)).Count();

    if (count >= 1)
    {
        xml.Descendants("Photos").Where(e => e.Attribute("File").Value.Equals(ID)).Remove();
    }
}
```

This time however it's on the `xml...Count()` line that is returning the error.

Any suggestions on how I can find out if a matching element exists please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
e.Attribute("File").Value.Equals(ID)
```

If this attribute is not present you will get a `NullReferenceException`. Instead you can use the [explicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your benefit:

```
var count = xml.Descendants("Photos")
               .Where(e => (string) e.Attribute("File") == ID)
               .Count();
```

This part is not really needed though, so just delete those items directly:

```
xml.Descendants("Photos")
   .Where(e => (string) e.Attribute("File") == ID)
   .Remove();
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, and it's great that it applies to the `.Remove()` function too which helps streamline my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `Value` property. Use an explicit cast and check the value of your Attribute using `==`

```
.Where(e => (string) e.Attribute("File") == ID)
```

This will not throw exception if the `Attribute` wasn't found, it will return `null` instead.